# JButton displays more than once after setting background image

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display text on the top and button in the center layout. But the output is a little weird. It displays a lot of buttons. What is wrong with this code?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePaneTest {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        TransparentPanel transparentPanel = new TransparentPanel(
                new BorderLayout());

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JLabel la = new JLabel("Title");
        p.add(la);
        p.setOpaque(false);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JButton la1 = new JButton("Button");
        p1.add(la1);
        p1.setOpaque(false);

        JFrame fr = new JFrame();

        fr.getContentPane().add(transparentPanel);
        transparentPanel.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        transparentPanel.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        fr.setSize(500, 500);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class TransparentPanel extends JPanel {

    public TransparentPanel(LayoutManager l) {
        super.setLayout(l);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                ImagePaneTest.class.getResource("/images/startback.jpg"));

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't load the image in a painting method. The painting methods are invoked whenever Swing determines a component needs to be repainted so the painting methods can be invoked many times and it doesn't make sense to read the image every time.

Comment: Sure. Thanks! What should be done to load the image in the first go itself? The background image appears after the frame is manually resized

Comment: the image should be loaded in the constructor. Also, the the "null" to "this" in the drawImage() method.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand this part - Also, the the "null" to "this" in the drawImage() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `super.paintComponent(g);` for custom painting code instead of `paintComponents`. `paintComponents` is left 
to the API to be called when needed

From http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html:

> Swing programs should override paintComponent() instead of overriding
>   paint(). Although the API allows it, there is generally no reason to
>   override paintBorder() or paintComponents() (and if you do, make sure
>   you know what you're doing!).

EDIT: I Just saw you are overriding `paintComponent`, so the super call should be to `paintComponent` too

Comment: What should be done to load the image in the first go itself? The background image appears after the frame is manually resized

Comment: @user1739812 I tried it and the image loads without need to resize

Comment: Oh thats' weird! Did you use the same code as above? I still see blank background!

Comment: @user1739812 That same code (with TransparentPanel in another file), eclipse juno sr2 and javaSE 1.7. And a image of 300x400.

Comment: @user1739812 I just did another test with another image (on of the demo images included in windows) and got that problem. Resized the image to be 300x400 and problem got solved

Answer (score 2):

It should be `super.paintComponent(g);`

```
@Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                    ImagePaneTest.class.getResource("/images/startback.jpg"));

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
```

Comment: Doing this, the image only appears when resizing the window (forcing java to call paintComponent).

Comment: @Imzaki: Since I don't have the image with me,can you tell what are you using it for?

Comment: I'm not the requester, I just pointed it out. ;) I replaced the image with one I had available for testing purposes. It seems to be the background image of the application.

Comment: Again: I'm not `user1739812`, but yes, the image and application works like charm, as soon as the window is resized a tiny bit (to force the update).

Comment: @Imzaki: Sorry I just got confused with the name of the requester and thought you as him.Sorry Sorry

Comment: What should be done to load the image in the first go itself? The background image appears after the frame is manually resized